# Why is 'on' not adding dynamically created elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I have a DIV with an ID:

```
<div id="List"></div>
```

Within this, there is server-rendered content and client content.  The server content is rendered in my MVC view:

```
@foreach (var item in items)
{
    <div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-4">
           <input .. />
       </div>
       .
       .
    </div>
}
```

I have a client-templating process (using Kendo UI) that also adds the same exact markup to the list element, using the script below:

```
var templateHtml = $("#Template").html();
var template = kendo.template(templateHtml);
var result = template({
   FirstName: "",
   LastName: ""
});

$("#List").append(result);
```

I was hoping to target the client and server code in one event call, like the following:

```
  $(function() {
      $("#List").on("change", "input", function(e) {
         //Do something
      });
  });
```

But this isn't firing for both server and client inputs generated in the UI; only the ones that exist at the time of the event creation.  Reading documentation for `on` suggests it should be on dynamic elements too?

Comment: Are you sure? The `change` event only fires when the input loses focus.

Comment: first of all , what do you mean server content from MVC?? that means this content is added when the page first gets loaded .  Way before jquery or Kendo ever getting loaded .  So for those changes obicously it won't fire.  For the Kendo changes to inputs, why can't you trigger something from the code that does the changing?

Comment: Server content is rendered in MVC view, which means my on("change", "input", ..) handler tracks these changes.  That works fine because it's loaded in the DOM.  According to documentation, on should automatically attach to inputs for appended content, which it is not...